# Error in External table output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, external

I am using external table to load a csv file data into oracle db table.

In the csv file i have few records which are written like

[image]

The external table query is :

```
CREATE TABLE XXH_preemp_EXT
(
type varchar2(1000),
PERSON_NUMBER varchar2(1000),
DATE_FROM date,
START_DATE date,
END_DATE date,
EMPLOYER_NAME varchar2(1000),
JOB_ROLE varchar2(1000),
ENDING_POS varchar2(1000),
source varchar2(1000)



)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY INTF_DIR_INBOUND
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( Records Delimited By Newline Skip 1
         BADFILE INTF_DIR_INBOUND:'prev_emp.bad'
         LOGFILE INTF_DIR_INBOUND:'prev_emp.log'
         NODISCARDFILE
         FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
         REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
         (
         Content_Type ,
PERSON_NUMBER ,
DATE_FROM date 'yyyy/mm/dd',
START_DATE date 'yyyy/mm/dd',
END_DATE date 'yyyy/mm/dd',
EMPLOYER_NAME ,
JOB_ROLE ,
ending_pos ,
SourceSystemOwner
         )
            )
     LOCATION (INTF_DIR_INBOUND:'Prev_emp.csv')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
NOPARALLEL
nomonitoring;
```

When i am checking the bad file. The 
""Special Assistant to the VP of Finance" is not being considered in one block and is being considered as two rows.

Screenshot from bad log :
[image]

There are 84 records in the bad file. Is there any other way out than manually correcting the file ?

Comment: Could it be a a line feed or carriage return contained within the field that is causing oracle to split and believe it is 2 rows?

Comment: Yes might be... seems line carriage return